# Send and receive a JSON class throught a POST method (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, jax-rs

I'm trying to call a POST method with a class like input and get a collection in result from server, like I do with a junit test that you can see below:

```
@Test
public void test_m11() {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    MyInput i = new MyInput();
    i.setNumero(33);
    i.setTesto("OK");

    Collection<MyPojo> a = client.target(testURL + "m11")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(Entity.json(i), Collection.class);
            //.get(Collection.class);

    System.out.println("test_m11 " + a.size());

    assertEquals(2, a.size());
}
```

But seem impossible for me!
I tryed with this script without any succesful result:

```
    var myi = {
        testo: "yeah",
        numero: "33"
    };

    // jquery-1.12.0.js & json2.js
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/WebServices/rest/test/m11",

        JSON.stringify(myi),
        function(data){

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                $('#r11').append(key + " " + value);
            });
        }, "json");
```

What's wrong with what I am doing? Can you drop me some advice?

Do you know any site where I can approach more deeply examples about class sent / received by JS (POST)?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did a connection go out? did you get a response back? does data (from the callback) contain anything?

Comment: if i recall a GET method slightly different from this for receiving a JSON response all go well, when i try to send an object via POST the method on server (m11) is not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the long hand version of what you are trying to do.

```
    var myi = {
        testo: "yeah",
        numero: "33"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/WebServices/rest/test/m11",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(myi)
    })
        .done(function () {
            // Handle good response
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            // Handle bad response
        });
```